# How to raise more than one exception in python

Tags: python, if-statement, exception

I try to raise more than one exception in an if-else branch:
The code is the following:

```
x = input()
try:
    if int(x) < 0: # the number should not be a negative number
        raise("This is a negative number.")
    if int(x) >= 4:
        print("That a lot.")
    else:
        print("That is not so much.")
except ValueError: # the input should be a other than a number
    print("You did not entered a number.")
```

The following error message occurs:
TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException

Comment: You cannot type `raise("This is a negative number.")`. Instead `raise` requires a valid exception class, e.g. `raise ValueError('This is a negative number.')`

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom class eg

```
class MyAwesomeException(AttributeError, KeyError):
    """
    This exception occurs when an unknown language is requested.
    """
```

and then in the code

```
raise MyAwesomeException(
                'Language `{}` is not a valid language name or '
                'not recognized by the program.'.format(item))
```